# How to use relative path when using UBT to build Unreal visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, build, unreal-engine4

I am using UnrealBuildTool (UBT) to build the Unreal Engine 4 source code.

This is the code:

```
UnrealBuildTool.exe -projectfiles -project="C:/projectname/projectname.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
```

Right now only full project path works for the -project parameter, is there a way to use relative path, like:

```
UnrealBuildTool.exe -projectfiles -project="projectname/projectname.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
```

Answer (score 0):

In your folder structure, do you have a file called "ue4games.uprojectdirs"? If not, you can create it(it's a text file) to tell the engine where to find project folders.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Basics/DirectoryStructure/